# Apache Shiro Permissions: How to implement any of permission check

Tags: shiro

I have a list of the following permissions:

```
book:download:red,
book:download:blue,
book:download:green
```

Now, I want to check whether the subject has any of those permissions set. If at least one of them is present, - permit.

So, on my REST controller, I am slapping this annotation with value:

`@RequiresPermissions(value = book:download:*)`

It means in my case, the subject has at minimum one valid book it can download, - let him in!

But, to my surprise, I get 403 with:

```
Subject does not have permission [book:download:*]
```

I would expect Shiro to use this wildcard and compare it against submitted permission like a REGEX check. And a result would have been - access allowed.

Please correct me if my understanding is wrong. And is there is a way to achieve what I am asking here?

Answer (score 1):

Think of the match the other way, your resource has a specific permission "`book:download:red`" and your user can download any book because they have a more general permission `book:download` or `book:download:*` (or the same specific `red` permission)

You can also configure the annotation to use a logical "OR", where you could use your list of `red`, `blue`, or `green`
https://shiro.apache.org/static/1.7.1/apidocs/org/apache/shiro/authz/annotation/RequiresPermissions.html

See more: https://shiro.apache.org/permissions.html

Comment: I know that the framework wants me to think that I need to operate the most restrictive permission on the annotation level. 
ORing does work, but what if you have plenty of permissions that you have to OR? That becomes a very polluted interface, right? Wouldn't it be nice if we had some syntactic sugar for cases like that?

Comment: Anyways, I had to introduce my own wildcard, override some of the `isPermitted` methods of `AuthorizingRealm` to perform an expansion of the wildcard into the collection of known permissions.

Answer (score 0):

you can use something like following:

```
@RequiresPermissions(value=
{PermissionsConstants.BOOK_DOWNLOAD_RED,
PermissionsConstants.BOOK_DOWNLOAD_BLUE,
PermissionsConstants.BOOK_DOWNLOAD_GREEN}, logical = Logical.OR)
```